# throws Exception refactoring in java

Tags: java, exception, error-handling, refactoring, throws

I am changing my code from

```
Implementation 1 : 
public User getUser(String userid) {
    User user;
    try {
        // some code to get User

    }catch(InterruptedException e) {
        throw new CustomException();
    }

    return user;
}
```

to

```
Implementation 2 : 
public User getUser(String userid) {
    User user;

    try {
        // some code to get User

    }catch(InterruptedException e) {
        SomeHandlerInProject.throwCustomErr();
    }

    return user;
}


class SomeHandlerInProject {
    public static void throwCustomErr() {
        throw new CustomException();
    }
}
```

Implementation 2 gives compilation error that user might not be initialized, can someone help what am I missing here, seems very weird to me.

Comment: Please post the exact compilation error.

Comment: [ERROR] /pathtoClassFile.java:[1239,16] variable user might not have been initialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler doesn't know that `SomeHandlerInProject.throwCustomErr()` always throws an exception, so as far as the compilers code analysis goes, the method may return normally.

If it does, what would the value of `user` be? It wouldn't have a value, so the compiler complains about that, as it should. Remember, the class `SomeHandlerInProject` could be changed to not throw exception, without having to recompile the class with the `getUser()` method, so the compiler is correct to complain about it.

Even though *you* know the method always throws an exception, you still have to write the code as-if it doesn't, so you must assign a value to `user`, either by initializing it, or by assigning to it in the `catch` block.

If the goal is to share the logic needed to build the exception, you should make the helper method `return` the exception, not throw it, and let the caller do the `throw`. That way the compiler won't complain:

```
public User getUser(String userid) {
    User user;
    try {
        // some code to get User
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw SomeHandlerInProject.buildCustomErr();
    }
    return user;
}

class SomeHandlerInProject {
    public static CustomException buildCustomErr() {
        return new CustomException();
    }
}
```

The stacktrace remains the same, since it is the constructor location that is snapshot'd for the call stack.

Comment: You're right. I thought for a moment that the compiler will be smart enough to know if the method in the other class always throws an Exception. 

But it doesn't, that's because it complies file one at a time. :facepalm:

Thanks!